# A joke about explanation and understanding

Tags: colloquial-language

I want to translate a short joke into English. The result doesn't sound natural, though I guess the idea is pretty clear. How would you rephrase it to sound more colloquial and natural?

> Two professors in a university are talking after a lecture:
>
> - Fools! I've been explaining that thing to them over and over again. Even I could understand it finally!

(This is my first question here, and I'm sorry if such questions are not appropriate for this website.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's a pretty funny joke. It made me laugh.

As for touching it up to make it sound like natural English, I can think of two small improvements:

1) Change "that thing" to "that **concept**", which seems like something a professor would be more likely to say.

2) I might tweak the wording of the punchline. One comment suggests:

- Even I can understand it now!

I might offer:

- Even I could finally understand it!

There is something about putting the word *finally* at the very end that makes it sound just a little bit off, but not so much so that I'd call it awkward.

This isn't universal, though; there are times when *finally* sounds best at the end of a sentence. However, in this case, I think it sounds a little better in front of *understand*.